# Json - сериализация/десиариализация нескольких значений в одно свойство

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Скажем, сервер возвращает json:

```
{
  "result": null, 
  "error": "error text",
  "exception": ""
}
```

Текст ошибки может прийти либо в `error`, либо в `exception`.
Создаем класс:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public T Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

**Вопрос**:
Можно как-то десериализовать значения из `error`, `exception` в одно свойство `Error`?

Comment: Как вы это себе видите? Как строку, которая является конкатенацией строк error и exception или отдельным классом с двумя свойствами?

Comment: @AK, как конкатенация, например. В ответе может прийти что-то одно или и `error` и `exception`, а в классе нужно чтобы было только одно свойство `Error`

Answer (score 2):

Это имелось в виду?

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public T Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string __Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("exception")]
    public string __Except { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Error { get { return String.Format("{0}, {1}", __Error, __Except); }}
}
```

Можно ещё реализовать конструктор для реализации свойств `private set;` для полей `__Error` и `__Except`, что бы не было возможности их изменить после получения, но это уже плюшечки..

Или ещё кастомный вариант оформления поля `Error`:

```
public string Error { 
    get {
          int c = (int)(__Error  != String.Empty) * 1 +
                  (int)(__Except != String.Empty) * 2;
          switch (c)
          {
              default: return "no errors";
              case  1: return String.Format("Error: {0}", __Error);
              case  2: return String.Format("Exception: {0}", __Except);
              case  3: return String.Format("{0}, {1}", __Error, __Except);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Примерно, только для ошибки должно быть одно публичное свойство. Можно сделать первые два приватными, не знаю будет ли тогда сереалзовать/десериализовать. Пока не могу проверить. Но вообще хотелось бы сделать более гибко, с возможностью задать разные настройки сереализации и десериализации, как в конвертерах.

Comment: Так оно так и есть в примере, свойство Error, настройки как в конвертах можно реализовать запилив свой класс атрибутов, но нужность этого сомнительна, на мой взгляд. Или есть желание чтоб эти два поля были не видны снаружи в структуре?

Comment: Вопрос скорее теоретический, хотелось бы узнать все способы. Да, не нужно выставлять наружу.

Comment: Если сериализатор ест конструктор, то можно прописать все поля в конструкторе, а сами эти два поля обозначить как приватные. Но это зависит от устройства сериализатора, как он к полям обращается.

Answer (score 2):

Если мы говорим о библиотеке newtonsoft, то это вполне можно реализовать с помощью JsonConstructor.

Посмотреть можно тут: [JsonConstructorAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute)

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомлюсь подробно позже. Как параметры передаются в конструктор? По названию или по порядку? Скажем если одного из параметров не будет в json, попадут ли следующие на свои места?

Comment: И еще, по ссылке что вы дали, чуть выше есть еще атрибут `OnDeserialized`, мне кажется он лучше подходит.